# can this code can be translated to stateful akka streams?

Tags: akka, amazon-sqs, akka-stream

[image]I'm trying to listen to sqs using akka streams and i get messages from it's q 
using this code snippet:

of course this code snippet get messages one-by-one (then ack it):

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ioThreadPoolSize))
val awsSqsClient: AmazonSQSAsync = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
  .standard()
  .withCredentials(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider())
  .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(sqsEndpoint, configuration.regionName))
  .build()

val future = SqsSource(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient)
  .takeWhile(_ => true)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 2)(m => {
    val msgBody = SqsMessage.deserializeJson(m.getBody)
    msgBody match {
      case Right(body) => val id = getId(body) //do some stuff with the message may save state according the id
    }
    Future(m, Ack())
  })
  .to(SqsAckSink(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient))
  .run()
```

my question is:
can i get several messages, and save them for example in a stateful map for latter use?

for example that after receiving 5 messages (all of them will saved (per state))

then if specific condition happens i will ack them all, and if not they will return into queue (will happen anyway because visibility timeout)?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you're looking for `grouped` (or `groupedWithin`) combinator. These allow you to batch messages and process them in groups. `groupedWithin` allows you to release a batch after a certain time in case it hasn't yet reached your determined size. Docs reference [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#grouped).

In a subsequent check flow you can perform any logic you need, and emit the sequence in case you want the messages to be acked, or not emit them otherwise.

Example:

```
  val yourCheck: Flow[Seq[MessageActionPair], Seq[MessageActionPair], NotUsed] = ???

  val future = SqsSource(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient)
    .takeWhile(_ => true)
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 2){ ... }
    .grouped(5)
    .via(yourCheck)
    .mapConcat(identity)
    .to(SqsAckSink(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient))
    .run()
```

Comment: i get Error:(115, 18) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message, akka.stream.alpakka.sqs.MessageAction)] => Seq[(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message, akka.stream.alpakka.sqs.MessageAction)]
 required: Seq[(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message, akka.stream.alpakka.sqs.MessageAction)] => scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[?]
      .mapConcat(identity)

Comment: Be sure you import  `immutable.Seq`. typesystem gets confused with the non-immutable `Seq`

Comment: I've set    val yourCheck: Flow[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[MessageActionPair], scala.collection.immutable.Seq[MessageActionPair], NotUsed] = ???                        but i get :Error:(115, 12) forward reference extends over definition of value yourCheck
      .via(yourCheck)

Comment: Hi Stefano can you elaborate please?

Comment: please amend your question with the failing code, otherwise I won't be able to reproduce this..

Comment: Hi Stefano. I've attached a picture that descibe the errors because it hard to read it as a text

Comment: Strfano can u elaborate?